# Javadoc formatting hyperlinks

Tags: java, formatting, javadoc

I can't seem to find out how to format my javadoc to show
to show up with links to String rather than the whole path. I've gone through several different [guides](http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#javadocoptions) with no luck.

[image]

I was hoping to make it look more in line with how documents at oracle look.

Comment: My machine didn't like the `http` URLs given in the linked guide. It did like `https`, as given in the answer. To give some examples for anyone searching for this:

YES:
`javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/`
`javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`
`javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`

NO:
`javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/`
`javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`
`javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`
`javadoc -link http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190312, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run javadoc with the `-link` or `-linkoffline` parameter and point it to Oracle's javadoc:

```
> javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ src/*
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to creating javadoc, so my next question would be where exactly do I write that bit? From what I read I didn't manage to figure out that, and is it supposed to be a > or a %? What I read in those guides was %javadoc so I'm just wondering if there is any difference

Comment: I used `>` to denote the command prompt. Many guides use the `%` character for the same purpose. How are you running javadoc?

Comment: I've been running it through netbeans. It has been more or less been generating it automatically for me. I just did the /** ... */ bit on top of classes and methods.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Netbeans, but look for a way to supply javadoc custom arguments, and add `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`.

Comment: After a while I found the place to add the link, if you press Run on the toolbar on the dropdown menu there there's an option to Set project configuration.
On the category list go to the subcategory of Build called Documenting. Copy the link you gave me onto the field named "Additional Javadoc Options" That fixed it for me!